# How can I disable semicolon electric behaviour without impacting the other electric chars in CC-mode?

Tags: cc-mode

In CC-mode when the electric behavior of characters is enabled, typing the semicolon character triggers the `c-electric-semi&comma` command.  That inserts the semicolon, terminates the line, moves point to next line and indents it.

**Question**:
How can I disable this electric behaviour of the semicolon temporarily, while retaining the electric behaviour of the other characters?

For example, I'd do that when I want to write several lines with comments at the end of the line, so I'd be able to type the semicolon and stay on the same line so I can write the C or C++ style comment at the end of the line.

I know how to disable RET electric behaviour (by removing it from the `electric-indent-char` list).  But `?;` is not part of that list when the semicolon is exhibiting electric behaviour.

Comment: Easiest way I know of is to quote the character before typing it: “C-q ;”

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought of that.